# How to Edit a Polyline in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Directions Service of Google Maps V3 API, and I want to reduce the length of one of the steps by 1m (lets say its the final step).

**Problem:** The `directionResult` can be seen [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false). The polyline is defined by a jumble of  characters. How can I extract the coordinates *(if required)* and shorten the polyline by 1m?

**Example of a polyline defination**

```
"polyline" : {
    "points" : "eir~FdezuOhFIF?HAdFG"
 },
```

**Javascript Code**

*Contains no code for shortening the polyline. Displays a set of markers at the start of every step*

```
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var start = target_latlng;
    var end = markers[i].getPosition();
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(directionResult, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            route = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
            for(var i = 0; i < route.steps.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: route.steps[i].start_location,
                    map: map
                });


                route.steps[i].polyline.points.getPath(); // does not work!


            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getPath()` should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to extract coordinates from polyline you can directly access the coordinates which eventually would be very similar to the polyline. You can access the fine coordinates at

```
result.routes[current_route].legs[0].steps[current_step].path
```

I know this works because I am successfully using it.

Let me know if this does not work.

axs